# How do I extrude using keyboard commands

Tags: edit-mode, extrude

I am creating simple roof 'hipped' on a building (mesh cube) and want to give it a precise 'thickness'.
What is the correct method?
I have tried divided the top surface of the cuve with loop cut, selected the edge and extruded on the Z axis with a keyboard command eg  E Z 55.
To give it thickness I have tried selecting each (top) face of the roof using a keyboard command E Z 0.2  which does not work for me.
I have also tried using the extrude 'tool' but cannot work out how to extrude a precise amount eg 0.2
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you press E then 0.2 right away it will give your roof a thickness of 0.2 as expected...

Comment: And so it does. I assumed (obviously incorrectly) that after pressing E   I needed to press the axis I wanted to extrude along (and then 0.2  eg  E Z 0.2)). Does Extrude always default to the Z axis otherwise why doesn't it extrude along say the X axis?

Comment: The faces Z axis is the face normal axis, so it makes sense that by default it will extrude along the faces Z axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extruding using <kbd>E</kbd> will by default use an axis that is normal to the faces.

In your situation, as the roof is symmetrical, this will be Z.

If you hit <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, that will remove this default axis, and let you extrude following the mouse movements.

So you just need to press <kbd>E</kbd> then the value you want.

If you want to use the extrude tool, simply use it then go to the operator panel and enter the value you want:

[image]